# $\mu \otimes \nu(A \times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, set-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(X,\mathcal{C},\nu)$ be to measure spaces with s-finite measures (so $\mu(\Omega)>0$ and $\mu(X)>0$).

Show that $\mu \otimes \nu(A \times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$ for $A\times B \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{C}$
and that if they are $\Sigma-$finite measures then $\mu \otimes \nu$ is uniquely determined by its values on $A\times B \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{C}$

---

I know that they are finite it is simply that the measure is $<\infty$. Further, it is s-finite if $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n$ where each $\mu_n$ is a finite measure. For it to be $\Sigma$-finite if the underlying set is a countable union of measurable sets with finite measure which is of course a weaker condition than finite.

I do not know how to proceed to solve the question with the definitions. For the uniqueness I was thinking about Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\mu \otimes \nu)(A \times B) = \mu(A)\nu(B)$ is part of the definition of the product measure (my definition uses Caratheodory's theorem to extend this rule to a measure on the product sigma-algebra).

As for uniqueness, suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra that generates a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$. Suppose $\mu, \nu$ are measures on the measurable space $(X, \mathcal{F})$ that agree on $\mathcal{A}$. Suppose there exist $A_j \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A_j) = \nu(A_j) < \infty$ such that $X = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty}A_j$. Then $\mu = \nu$. When $\mu(X) = \nu(X) < \infty$, this is a consequence of the monotone class theorem. Otherwise, apply the previous case to each $A_j$ (after making them disjoint). I think the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem can also work here.

Comment: Yes the $\pi-\lambda$-theorem also works here.

Comment: Why does the argument work in terms of Monotone class theorem

Comment: @math mat I forgot to say that $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on $\mathcal{A}$. When $X$ has finite measure, you can show that the collection $C = \{E \in \mathcal{F} : \mu(E) = \nu(E)\}$ is a monotone class that contains $\mathcal{A}$, hence $C = \mathcal{F}$.